# IIS URL Rewriting best practices for matching

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, iis

I'm deploying an Angular 5.x app that runs inside ASP.NET MVC. When doing this, I've considered the following options:

- Deploy it at "/" inside the web sites index.cshtml page
- Create it's own controller (so deploy it at "/myapp/")
- Create another virtual directory just for the Angular app.

The problem with the first item is that I have the Angular routes as well as other URL's that all hang off of "/".

The second item may be ok but I'm not sure how well rewriting back to "/subpage/" works. Opinions?

The third would make the URL Rewriting easy but would mess with the SAML based auth.

Assuming I go with the first or second choice, is there a good way to white list or black list a set of URLs for the rewrite rule. So that I can either say that this rule applies to all my angular routes or that it does not apply to my non-angular URLs.

Per LexLi's suggestion, I'm trying:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="Account/*" negate="true" ignoreCase="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="SAML/*" negate="true" ignoreCase="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="Sites/*" negate="true" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

However, the .* in the match is not working. If I put something more specific in, it does work.

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/iis-url-rewrite-tip-break-free-adccdb4b9f2f

Comment: This looks a good answer @LexLi, thanks! I'll let you know how it turns out.

Comment: Hey @LexLi, Add this as an answer and I'll accept it. One follow up if you know. I want my final rule to be ".*" to match any of the angular routes. For some reason this is not working and doesn't match. I have to create a rule for each angular route with "route1/*", "another/*", etc. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest you post your own answer. For the final rule, have you used failed request tracing to troubleshoot? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: I've posted my current rule that is working for the exception cases (Account, SAML, Sites) but does not work for the angular routes.